# Why is a specific flower offered to a deity?

Tags: puja

What is the Importance of flowers in puja ritual and why is a specific flower offered to a deity?

Comment: [Why is a specific flower offered to a deity?](https://www.hindujagruti.org/hinduism/knowledge/article/why-is-a-specific-flower-offered-to-a-deity.html)

Answer (score 3):

Flowers are intrinsic part of hindu worship and rituals. the fragrance of the flower pleases the deity. they create a pleasant and aesthetic value to the pooja ritual. they are symbol of happiness, prosperity and completion of purpose of life.

> Normally we have a concept that a deity is to be offered only that
>   flower which he/she likes. But is it really so? Let us see the actual
>   reason according to science of spirituality.
>
> A flower has a particular colour and a special fragrance. On a subtle
>   level the colour and fragrance particles present in the flower have a
>   capacity to attract the principles of a specific deity which benefits
>   the worshipper. That is the principle behind offering specific flowers
>   to a deity and not because they like it.
>
> To cite some examples white flower like that of Dhatura is offered to
>   Shiva, red coloured flower like Hibiscus for Shri Ganesh, and red
>   coloured flowers for Shri Durgadevi also. If the worshipper has more
>   spiritual emotion for these flowers then the frequencies of deities
>   get more activated through the medium of these flowers and work for
>   the worshipper directly.

**Offer only fresh flowers to the deity**

> According to religious scriptures on the science of spirituality, only
>   proper and best objects should be offered to a deity and the flowers
>   are no exception. Therefore the use of dried out flowers or those
>   infested with insects are prohibited in the ritualistic worship of a
>   deity. There are two reasons for this according to spiritual science:
>
> - Whatever we offer to a deity is accepted by the deity on a subtle    level and then They get pleased and bless us. Therefore whatever we
>     offer to Them has to be best.
> - The capacity of a flower to absorb and emit the frequencies of deity    and sattvik frequencies gets reduced if it is dry or infested
>     with    insects.

[Source](https://www.hindujagruti.org/hinduism/knowledge/article/why-is-a-specific-flower-offered-to-a-deity.html)

**Flowers offered to hindu gods and goddess**

> - **Lord ganesha** – any red color flower will do. however the red color    jaswanti flower (hibiscus) is favorite to ganesha. jaswanti
>     flower    comes in many different colors. so choose the red color if
>     possible.    you can also offer lotus, champa, rose, jasmine, yellow
>     and orange    marigold flowers. apart from this you can offer dhurva
>     grass blades    (1,3,5,7), bilva leaves and herbal leaves. usually 21
>     different    varieties of flowers and leaves are used while performing
>     ganesha    pooja.
>
>   - **lord shiva** – any white flower will do. you can offer maulshri, blue    lotus (if blue lotus is not there then you can offer pink
>       lotus or    white lotus) and kaner. bel leaves (9 or 10), dhatura
>       flowers,    naagkeshar, harsingar, and aak (aakamda) flowers are also
>       favorite of    shiva. however bilvapatra is most important in shiva
>       pooja.  in the    bilvapatra the chakra and the bajra should not be
>       there. the chakra    is a white mark made by the insects on the
>       bilvapatra, while the    bajra is the thick portion towards the stalk.
>       this part should be    broken. the bilvapatra half eaten up by the
>       insects is also not    considered good for worshipping shiva.
>   - **Goddess durga** – most red color flowers like hibiscus. you can also    offer lotus, mogra flower and bel leaves
>   - **Goddess parvati** – she is fond of all flowers offered to lord shiva.    apart from them you can offer bela, white lotus, palash,
>       madar,    apamarg, champa and chameli.
>   - **Lord vishnu** – he is very fond of lotus. you can offer pink lotus,    maulshri, juhi (jasmine), kadamb, kewra, chameli, champa,
>       ashok,    malti and basanti. tulsi leaves are dear to vishnu. so you
>       can offer
>   - **Goddess lakshmi** – she likes the lotus most. you can offer pink lotus,    yellow gaindha (marigold) and desi gulab/rose (not hybrid).
>       in fruits    you can offer one shriphal (bel fruit)
>   - **Lord brahma** – tagar and white lotus
>   - **Goddess saraswati** – any white flower or white lotus or palash    Flowers. goddess mahakali – yellow kaner
>   - **Lord saturn** – worship with blue color flowers. its done on saturday.
>   - Sun god (surya devata) – lotus flower
>
> **Flowers are not offered to gods**
>
> - **lord shiva** – champa (champaka) and ketaki or kewda (fragrant screw    pine). because it was cursed by lord shiva along with lord
>     brahma for    lying.
> - **lord ganesha**- ketaki flower and tulsi (holy basil). read why tulsi is    not offered to lord ganesha.
> - **goddess parvati** – arka (milkweeds) and amla (indian gooseberry)
> - lord vishnu – ‘aksada’ is not used in pooja
> - **lord rama** – arali (nerium oleander)
> - **sun god** **(surya devta)** – vilva (bilva or bael leaves)
> - **lord bairava** – nandyarvattam (east indian rosebay, crape jasmine)

[Source](http://www.thespiritualindian.com/flowers-offered-to-hindu-gods-and-goddess/)

Comment: Could you please tell what AKSADA flower is.